# Find time period in list of status changes (per status)

Tags: sql, datetime, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list of moments a specific user does something on a specific workstation:

```
    station timestamp
    TC61879 2016-03-25 09:34:40.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 09:38:36.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:01:17.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:02:10.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:04:01.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:04:43.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:05:49.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:06:00.000
    TC61878 2016-03-25 10:08:05.000*
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:09:41.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:10:40.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:35:50.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:37:57.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:38:21.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:39:34.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:40:59.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:41:20.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:42:21.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:44:05.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:44:17.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:46:25.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:47:48.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:49:03.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:51:31.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:51:58.000
    TC61875 2016-03-25 10:52:42.000*
    TC61875 2016-03-25 10:53:49.000*
    TC61879 2016-03-25 10:53:57.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:36:58.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:37:37.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:38:45.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:40:08.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:41:46.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:43:43.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:44:49.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:46:06.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:48:17.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:50:22.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:52:06.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:52:22.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:53:07.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:55:29.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:55:49.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:56:24.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:57:20.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:57:55.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:58:15.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:59:05.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 11:59:17.000
    TC61878 2016-03-25 11:59:52.000*
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:00:08.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:01:04.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:01:36.000
    TC61878 2016-03-25 12:04:42.000*
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:04:46.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:05:37.000
    TC61878 2016-03-25 12:07:37.000*
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:07:47.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:08:36.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:10:16.000
    TC61879 2016-03-25 12:11:30.000
```

Asterisk is when a user did something on a different workstation than his default one. What is need is a list of from-to per workstation, like this:

```
Station      From                       To
TC61879      2016-03-25 09:34:40.000    2016-03-25 10:08:05.000
TC61878      2016-03-25 10:08:05.000    2016-03-25 10:09:41.000
TC61879      2016-03-25 10:09:41.000    2016-03-25 10:52:42.000
TC61875      2016-03-25 10:52:42.000    2016-03-25 10:53:57.000
TC61879      2016-03-25 10:53:57.000    2016-03-25 11:59:52.000
TC61878      2016-03-25 11:59:52.000    2016-03-25 12:00:08.000
TC61879      2016-03-25 12:00:08.000    2016-03-25 12:04:42.000
TC61878      2016-03-25 12:04:42.000    2016-03-25 12:04:46.000
TC61879      2016-03-25 12:04:46.000    2016-03-25 12:07:37.000
TC61878      2016-03-25 12:07:37.000    2016-03-25 12:07:47.000
TC61879      2016-03-25 12:07:47.000    2016-03-25 12:11:30.000
```

I have tried various things with window functions and joins, but I keep having the problem that, when a users switches from one workstation to another and back the data does not reflect when the user did something on the other workstation.

```
select station from resulttable where @datetime between from and to
```

This query should only give one row as a result

Eventually I want to use this data do determine where a user in any given datetime.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to assign groups based on changes in a column (ordered by time).  There is a "trick" using the difference of row numbers that makes this quite easy:

```
select station, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum_t,
             row_number() over (partition by station order by timestamp) as seqnum_wst
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum_t - seqnum_wst), station;
```

If you look at the sequential numbers that are generated, the first is enumerating the rows.  The second enumerates the rows within each station.  When the rows are sequential, then the difference is constant.

Comment: I was so close, yet so far away. Would never have thought of a solution like this. Thanks!

Comment: pls help if you can for related questions in mongoDB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067856/calculate-dwell-time-between-2-statuses-of-a-field