# MongoDB: Calculate dwell time between every status value change

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find out the dwell time between every presenceStatus change.

Example collection -

```
   /* 1 */

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889a7c7959f6a13039902"),
    "presenceStatus" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:14:35.121Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:14:35.121Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889a7c7959f6a1303990c"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:35.121Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:35.121Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
/* 3 */

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889a9c7959f6a1303995c"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:37.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:37.420Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:37.420Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889b0c7959f6a130399ff"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:44.316Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:44.316Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889b3c7959f6a13039a58"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:47.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:47.181Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:47.181Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889b5c7959f6a13039aad"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:49.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:49.545Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:49.545Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889b9c7959f6a13039b28"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:53.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:53.389Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:53.389Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889bcc7959f6a13039b78"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:56.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:56.007Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:56.007Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889bfc7959f6a13039c00"),
    "presenceStatus" : 1,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:59.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:59.619Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:59.619Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4889c2c7959f6a13039c4a"),
    "presenceStatus" : 0,
    "sensingTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:16:02.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:16:02.100Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:16:02.100Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As you can see presenceStatus changed in 2nd document from value 0 to 1.

I want to record this dwell Time period when the status remained 1. (basically time difference between status = 1 to status = 0 )

The same process starts again when it finds presenceStatus 1 again and records the time-period when presenceStatus remained 1 for that chunk of data.

Result collection would look like -

```
{
    "_id" : xxx
    "occupiedTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:15:35.121Z"), //  *updatedAt* value of document 2, cause that's when it changed to 1. 

    "vacantTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:16:02.100Z"), // *updatedAt* of document 10, because that's when status changed from 0 to 1. 
    "dwellTime" : (vacant time - occupied time in HH:MM:SS)
    "created" : "2019-05-29 07:08:13",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did `"07:00:53"` come from? I mean how it's supposed to be calculated?

Comment: I updated my question with some more details. "07:00:53" is basically time value extracted from the first document when the presenceStatus was found to be 1.

Comment: some help is appreciated.

Comment: @newdeveloper : I guess this logging is happening for one device ? Anyway doing this on entire collection is not feasible, you may need to consider doing this for a day's data or on a month's data that too depends on how many docs being accumulated on daily basis & also use-case on how often it can turn 0 - 1 or vice versa, cause if device is 0 for 5 months we can't do this operation for just 1month as we will miss rest 4months time..

Comment: @whoami This is actually part of our data aggregation job that run daily basis. logging happens for several devices and I have to find a way to find dwell time as mentioned for each device. I am taking it step by step by posting this first question on how to find dwell time each time when value changes from 1 to 0.

Comment: @whoami let me know if you need more data to test this out on playground?

Comment: Confirm please: Do you have at least MongoDb >=v3.6?

Comment: @Valijon yes I have v4.0.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Valijon, @Plancke 
Thanks all who helped. we chose to take a different approach and turned our a simple for loop was able to do the job for now. Thanks again.
Here is final solution if any one was interested:

```
let prevSensingResults = {}; 

db.sensingresults.find({updatedAt : {$gt :"",$lte : "")}, presenceStatus : {$exists: 1}}).sort({updatedAt:1})
.forEach(function(doc) { 
    if (typeof prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()] !== undefined) {
         if (prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()].presenceStatus !== doc.presenceStatus && doc.presenceStatus === 0) {
             db.presenceagg.update({accountId: doc.accountId, buildingId: doc.buildingId, gatewayId: doc.gatewayId, deviceId: doc.deviceId, occupiedTime: prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()].updatedAt, vacantTime: doc.updatedAt}
         , {accountId: doc.accountId, buildingId: doc.buildingId, gatewayId: doc.gatewayId, deviceId: doc.deviceId, occupiedTime: prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()].updatedAt, vacantTime: doc.updatedAt, dwellPeriodInSeconds: (doc.updatedAt.getTime() - prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()].updatedAt.getTime()) / 1000}
                 , {upsert:true});
            prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()] = doc;
         } else if (prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()].presenceStatus !== doc.presenceStatus && doc.presenceStatus === 1) 
            prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()] = doc;
      }
    } else {
        prevSensingResults[doc.deviceId.toString()] = doc;
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if this solution meets your requirements.

## Explanation

1. We join over the same collection. So for each item <sub>i</sub> we take item <sub>i+1</sub>. This method gives us where `presenceStatus` has been changed.
2. We filter document<sub>i i+1</sub> pairs where `presenceStatus` is `0 - 1` or `1 - 0`.
3. We group them into single `data` array.
4. Now we iterate over `data` by 2 steps `(i=0;i<data.length;i+=2)` and take `updatedAt` value.

```
    var occupiedTime = data[i].tmp.updatedAt
    var vacantTime   = data[i+1].tmp.updatedAt
```

5. We flatten calculated values and restore original document structure.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        root_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                "$_id",
                "$$root_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "presenceStatus": 1,
          "tmp.presenceStatus": 0
        },
        {
          "presenceStatus": 0,
          "tmp.presenceStatus": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$ROOT",
            {
              tmp: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$tmp",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$data"
              },
              2
            ]
          },
          as: "idx",
          in: {
            "occupiedTime": {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data.tmp.updatedAt",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$data.tmp.presenceStatus",
                            "$$idx"
                          ]
                        },
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$idx",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        "$$idx",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "vacantTime": {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data.tmp.updatedAt",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$data.tmp.presenceStatus",
                            "$$idx"
                          ]
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$idx",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        "$$idx",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "created": {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data.tmp.createdAt",
                "$$idx"
              ]
            },
            "_id": {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data.tmp._id",
                "$$idx"
              ]
            },
            "__v": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "dwellTime": {
        $dateToString: {
          date: {
            $toDate: {
              $subtract: [
                "$vacantTime",
                "$occupiedTime"
              ]
            }
          },
          format: "%H-%M-%S"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MalSCuhiY1H)

Comment: This is some great work. Please look at this again - https://mongoplayground.net/p/kYa7bAAim20  I changed presenceStatus for first document and now result shows null for dwelltime.

Comment: we have to start aggregating when first document with presenceStatus comes as 1. so if first document 's presenceStatus = 1 then thats our first tmp document. and then first presenceStatus  = 0 is our break point.

Comment: Also, I tired to filter presenceStatus: { $in: [0, 1] }, in $match but not working. we need to consider presenceStatus with 0 and 1 value only.

Comment: @newdeveloper Check my answer, I've updated the code.

Comment: I just checked your new playground changes, it is still shows null dwellTime in result.

Comment: @newdeveloper it shows null because `0 -- 1` relationship is odd

Comment: I need your expertise on look up again on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109179/mongodb-find-deeply-nested-object-with-lookup?noredirect=1#comment108111460_61109179

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) on the collection, this will output the difference in seconds, but that should be relatively easy to change on your end.

I haven't used this method on any sizeable collections, nor at all recently, so I'm not aware of performance implications by doing it in this fashion, please refer to the docs for more information.

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(0, this);
  },
  function(key,values){
    var state = values[0].presenceStatus;
    var stateTimestamp = values[0].updatedAt;
    var result = {
      changes: []
    };

    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
      var value = values[i];
      if (value.presenceStatus !== state) {
        if (state === 1) {
          result.changes.push({
            "dwellTime": value.updatedAt - stateTimestamp,
            "occupiedTime": value.updatedAt,
          });
        }

        state = value.presenceStatus;
        stateTimestamp = value.updatedAt;
      }
    }

    return result;
  },
  {
    out: { inline: 1 }
  }
).results[0].value.changes;
```

```js
[
        {
                "dwellTime" : 26979,
                "occupiedTime" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:16:02.100Z")
        }
]
```

Comment: did you try this on mongo playground?

Comment: I tried the solution here and gives an error - https://mongoplayground.net/p/1osX3aBxd0P

Comment: Also I will also need to find "vacantTime"  which is really next document time when status became 0 from 1.