# Create a sort of "tabular" projection using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say that I have the following documents in a one of the stages in mongodb aggregation:

```
{
    type: "A",
    value: "A",
    index: 1
},
{
    type: "A",
    value: "B",
    index: 0
},
{
    type: "B",
    value: "a",
    index: 4
},
{
    type: "B"
    value: "b",
    index: 2
},
{
    type: "B",
    value: "c",
    index: 5
}
```

And I would like to process them using available aggregate stages (using syntax from Mongo 4.0) into:

```
{
    type: "A",
    values: ["B", "A", null, null, null, null]
},
{
    type: "B",
    values: [null, null, "b", null, "a", "c"]
}
```

I was trying to use `$project` with `$reduce` but still I don't know how to set element at a specific index.

EDIT: The size of `values` array is not given up-front. In the sample case it's assumed to be 6 because the largest index is 5. So `values` in every output document has to be aligned to that size.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the processed output? How did you get the _six_ elements in the `values` array?

Comment: @prasad_ good point - I added explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to sort by `index` and there should be `null, null, "b", "a", "c"` for `type B`. Then you can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { index: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            type: { $addToSet: "$type" }
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$type"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            type: 1,
            values: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$docs",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$type", "$$this.type" ] }, "$$this.value", null ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator allows you to build an array of unique `type` values which can be used then for [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html).

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p6u45wfrhnc)

Comment: pls help if you can for related questions in mongoDB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067856/calculate-dwell-time-between-2-statuses-of-a-field