# MongoDB - Calculate time difference between documents based on the existence of a value inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between the two documents but I'm not sure how to do this based on the existence of a value inside an array.

Let me explain in a little more detail. Say I have five documents: `A, B, C, D, E` in a collection.

Each document has `referenceKey`, `timestamp` and `persons` fields. 
And each element inside a `persons` array have `personType` field along with other fields:

```
A: { referenceKey: 1, timestamp: ISODate, persons: [ { personType: "ALICE", ... }, { personType: "BOB", ... } ] }
B: { referenceKey: 1, timestamp: ISODate, persons: [ { personType: "ALICE", ... }, { personType: "BOB", ... } ] }
C: { referenceKey: 1, timestamp: ISODate, persons: [ { personType: "BOB", ... } ] }
D: { referenceKey: 1, timestamp: ISODate, persons: [ { personType: "ALICE", ... }, { personType: "BOB", ... } ] }
E: { referenceKey: 1, timestamp: ISODate, persons: [ { personType: "BOB", ... } ] }
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate how much time the person with type `ALICE` has spent for *each visit*.  
In other words, this should calculate and return an array of time differences:

```js
[{ timeSpent: C.timestamp - A.timestamp }, { timeSpent: E.timestamp - D.timestamp }]
```

Here is an example collection to test:

```js
[
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T20:00:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      },
      {
        personType: "ALICE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T20:10:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:00:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      },
      {
        personType: "ALICE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:15:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:20:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:45:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      },
      {
        personType: "ALICE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T22:05:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      },
      {
        personType: "ALICE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T23:00:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 1,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-12T18:30:00.000Z"),
    referenceKey: 2,
    persons: [
      {
        personType: "BOB"
      },
      {
        personType: "JOHN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I thought I can add a new boolean field `hasAlice` using `$in` based on the existence of person type `ALICE`. But the problem is the time spent calculation should be done for *each visit* so I cannot just use `$reduce` to calculate the total time. Can I somehow use `$group` by `hasAlice` field change and then use `$reduce`?

What I've tried (and failed) so far:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { // I also filter by timestamp and referenceKey but it is not relevant to the problem
      timestamp: {
        "$gte": ISODate("2019-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2019-04-12T23:59:00.000Z")
      },
      referenceKey: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      timestamp: 1,
      hasAlice: {
        "$in": [
          "ALICE",
          "$persons.personType"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      timestamp: 1
    }
  }
])
```

What I want to get:

```js
[
 { timeSpent: 10 }, // in minutes
 { timeSpent: 15 },
 { timeSpent: 75 },
]
```

What I actually get when I run the aggregation:

```js
[
  {
    "hasAlice": true, // 1. visit starts
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T20:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": false, // 1. visit ends
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T20:10:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": true, // 2. visit starts
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T21:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": false, // 2. visit ends
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T21:15:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": false,
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T21:20:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": true, // 3. visit starts
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T21:45:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": true, // NOTE: there are some misleading documents such as these (e.g. document B)
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T22:05:00Z")
  },
  {
    "hasAlice": false, // 3. visit ends
    "timestamp": ISODate("2019-04-12T23:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

I don't know if my logic is correct or can I somehow reduce these documents to calculate the time spent for each visit. But any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thanks to [this somewhat similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61081514/5492826).

The trick is to use `$lookup` to left-join the collection with *itself* and then getting the first element that does not contain the person type `ALICE` from the joined collection. This element from the joined collection gives us the ending of each visit (i.e `leaveTimestamp`).

From there, we can further `$group` by end of each visit and select only the first `timestamp` of matching documents so that we can eliminate any misleading documents (e.g. document `B`).

Here is the full `aggregate` pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      timestamp: {
        "$gte": ISODate("2019-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2019-04-12T23:59:00.000Z")
      },
      referenceKey: 1,
      persons: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "personType": "ALICE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      timestamp: 1,
      hasAlice: {
        "$in": [
          "ALICE",
          "$persons.personType"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        root_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            timestamp: {
              "$gte": ISODate("2019-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
              "$lt": ISODate("2019-04-12T23:59:00.000Z")
            },
            referenceKey: 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            timestamp: 1,
            hasAlice: {
              "$in": [
                "ALICE",
                "$persons.personType"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                "$_id",
                "$$root_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      timestamp: 1,
      tmp: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tmp",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.hasAlice",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      timestamp: 1,
      leaveTimestamp: {
        $first: "$tmp.timestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$leaveTimestamp",
      "timestamp": {
        "$min": "$timestamp"
      },
      leaveTimestamp: {
        $first: "$leaveTimestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "visitingTime": {
        $dateToString: {
          date: {
            $toDate: {
              $subtract: [
                "$leaveTimestamp",
                "$timestamp"
              ]
            }
          },
          format: "%H-%M-%S"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PI05dSllbuY)